# concatenating android canvas

Tags: android, canvas, construction

I am looking for an example for constructing a canvas with multiple bitmaps(kind of in a grid pattern).

would I need to create a single bitmap that holds all of the other bitmaps on top or can I just place each bitmap "into" the canvas (similar to concatenating a string)?

**note:** that I will also be placing additional images ontop of this constructed canvas (probably other bitmaps) would this cause any additional issues, or can I just add those right on-top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can possibly have an View with the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method drawing the grid you want using the `drawBitmap(...)` collection of methods of the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) class.

EDIT: This way you have to deal with z-order and all the positioning of course

Comment: so what your saying is that I can just make successive calls to canvas.drawBitmap() at render time (understanding that I would have to do math.   as an aside are images possitioned by top-left, or center.

Comment: I want to be able to move one of these front images(like a piece in a board game would I need to make special consideration for this by: removiing first position then placing second (so that i don't have to redraw the entire screen which can be expensive)

Comment: You can always store previous states of the canvas with/without the on-top image you want to be able to move. You can store this as a canvas or a bitmap as itself.